# Angular, show formgroup when model.id is larger than 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have an formgroup instance, and need to show input with formControlName attribute when "model.id > 0", else show an input without that attribute.

But when I do this I get an error "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in."

How can I resolve this?

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="margin_bottom__25">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="legalName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">{{'STRUCTURES_AND_BRANCHES.branch.branch' | translate}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="form-content" *ngIf="!stateVM.isLegalNameEditable">{{model.legalName}}</span>
      <input *ngIf="stateVM.isLegalName" formControlName="legalName" id="legalName" name="legalName" type="text" class="form-control"
        placeholder="{{'STRUCTURES_AND_BRANCHES.branch.branch_tab.basic_details.legalName_placeholder' | translate}}">
      <input *ngIf="model.id < 1" name="legalName" type="text" class="form-control"
             placeholder="{{'STRUCTURES_AND_BRANCHES.branch.branch_tab.basic_details.legalName_placeholder' | translate}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div *ngIf="!stateVM.isLegalNameEditable">
        <button [elementAccess]="FormEnum.HeadquarterAndBranch" class="btn btn-purple pull-right" (click)="toggleLegalNameEdit()">
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          <span>{{'STRUCTURES_AND_BRANCHES.branch.edit_btn' | translate}}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="stateVM.isLegalNameEditable">
        <button class="btn btn-purple pull-right" [disabled]="!form.controls['legalName'].valid" (click)="onLegalNameSave()">{{'STRUCTURES_AND_BRANCHES.branch.save_btn' | translate}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light-gray margin_right__5 pull-right" (click)="onCancelLegalName()">{{'STRUCTURES_AND_BRANCHES.branch.cancel_btn' | translate}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can try `[hidden]` Instead of `*ngIf`.

Comment: Please share the associated component file as well. Looks like the 'form' element isn't defined as a FormGroup in the component side

Comment: please include the relevant `*.ts` file

Comment: the error say you have NOT a variable "form" of type FormGroup. Usually you can enclose all in a < div *ngIf="form" >< form formGroup="form">...</form>< /div>. tip if you want to ask for a field of the form you can use form.get('name_of_field').value

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

```
[hidden]="model.id == 0"
```

> *ngIf if false will remove the element from the DOM
>
> [hidden] if true will set the display to none in css